# How do I delete a board when the admin is no longer part of the group?

Tags: trello

One of our programmers decided to leave us. We took him off the group, but his board that he is the only admin of is still hanging around. How do I remove it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is no longer relevant.

Comment: @RichArmstrong I'm not familiar with Trello, but are you saying there's no longer a means to adjust this setting with the script you have below?

Comment: I voted against closing this, as the question appears most relevant until the issue is fixed in Trello.

Comment: I will leave it open for the time being.  If we ultimately decide to close it and have voted to close and are unable to vote again due to the system, feel free to flag with "Other"

Answer (score 7):

Hmmm. It would appear that organization admins cannot remove boards from their org if they are not an admin of that particular board.

This would seem to be an oversight. You can contact us directly at `support@trello.com` to get this resolved in the meantime, but we need to make it so organization admins can remove boards regardless of their admin capability on those boards.

---

Also, the Trello API allows you to remove a board from within your organization, even if you're not an admin of that board. Until we get this added to the Trello site, here's a workaround for removing the board.

NOTE: You must be an org admin to perform this task.

1. Open up Google Chrome.
2. Log in and navigate to your organization's page in Trello.
3. Open the Chrome developer Console (Ctrl+Shift+J on Windows).
4. Paste in the following code and press enter:

   ```
   $(".board-list li").each(function(){ var $=jQuery; var li = this; var idBoard = /[^/]*$/.exec($(this).find("a").attr("href"))[0]; $("<div>").text("Remove From Org").appendTo(this).click(function(){ $.ajax({ type: "put", url: "/1/boards/" + idBoard + "/idOrganization", data: { value: "", token: $.cookie("token") }, success: function(){ $(li).remove(); } }); }); })
   ```
5. There will now be a bit of text that says "Remove From Org" below each board. If you click on that text, it will remove the board from your org. Careful! Once you remove it, you cannot get it back unless someone within your organization is an admin of that board.

Comment: the script no longer works. `regex` returns the wrong result. this works `$(".board-list li").each(function(){ var $=jQuery; var li = this; var idBoard = $(this).find("a").attr("href").split('/')[2]; $("<div>").text("Remove From Org").appendTo(this).click(function(){ $.ajax({ type: "put", url: "/1/boards/" + idBoard + "/idOrganization", data: { value: "", token: $.cookie("token") }, success: function(){ $(li).remove(); } }); }); })`

Answer (score 3):

Code from Rich's answer and comments to it didn't work for me any longer, so here's modified working code.

Keep in mind that **this will DELETE the board, *not close***. So you won't be able to reopen it later.

You have just to paste this in your [browser's console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console) when you are on team's main page ( `https://trello.com/TEAM_NAME` ):

```
$(".boards-page-board-section-list li").each(function(){
  var $=jQuery; var li = this; var idBoard = $(this).find("a").attr("href").split('/')[2];
  console.log(idBoard);
  $('<input type="button" value="Remove from Org" />"').appendTo(this).click( function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "put", url: "/1/boards/" + idBoard + "/closed", data: {
        value: "true", token: $.cookie("token")
      }, success: function(){
        $(li).remove();
      }, error: function(ts){
        alert(ts.responseText)
      }
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: Script not working anymore: split is called on undefined. But I hardcoded the idBoard instead, and could remove the lurking board! Thanks.